# How to apply border on the right and bottom only?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, photoshop-effects

I use 'Round Rectangle Tool' to create a rounded rectangle shape.

I want to apply dark gray border on the right and bottom of a rectangle shape (layer).

What is the solution to do this? I have tried to play around with Stroke (Position: Inside) from Blending option but no luck.

Comment: I always put in a separate layer, make rectangle, then delete unwanted lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use for example **Inner shadow** to do that.

Other potential Layer style ways of doing that would be: **Drop Shadow** and **Bevel and emboss**

---

Here's a bottom right border made with Inner shadow:

And  Those other mentioned Layer styles would also go by same basic idea. ( With drop shadow you could make a border that is set outside. )

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else searching for this, do your effect as you wish, duplicate the layer (for non destruct) hide the original, right click on the dupe layer and rasterize it. Then, you can modify it as needed.

Comment: this is very unscalable and difficult to modify