# How to set rectangle border on the bottom only?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Adobe Photoshop CS5 version 12.0

I try to add rectangle border bottom.

Example Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnVfK.png

Comment: What rectangle? No rectangles in your example have bottom-only borders. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: like white rectangle and border bottom

Comment: are you talking about borders (stroke) or a shadows? you have 2 white rectangles with shadows, is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Draw a line at the bottom. You can't add a "border" to anything short of 4 sides with Photoshop.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such feature. Think in terms of shapes... If you can draw a rectangle, you can draw that border too, by making a thin rectangle. — I'd likely duplicate the rectangle `cmd+j` then make it smaller with free transform `cmd+t` and change it's color. — Newer PS versions do allow you do add border to shapes sort of like you can in AI, but no option for individual sides.

Comment: ok, thank you...

Comment: I just remembered something. Using a layer style would have a slight benefit, because then if you resize the rectangle, the scale of the stroke won't change and it would be stuck to the layer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/how-to-apply-border-on-the-right-and-bottom-only/6692#6692 — In your case you'd obviously use a different angle.

Comment: @Joonas tbh this is the kind of stuff that is so much better done in a vector program instead of Photoshop... Nowadays I'd recommend one of the prototyping-specific apps like Figma or Sketch.

Comment: @Luciano, sorta yea, but also no. You need to resort to similar trickery in all of those apps to add a bottom stroke or a single stroke on any of the sides. The only one I know that can do that is Webflow... But that is very website oriented and OP's thing could be a mobile app for all I know.

Comment: @Joonas indeed, I wouldn't use any of these softwares for adding 1 border on a rectangle; my starting point is already that I wouldn't use a rectangle.